# Can I go for in-line specification of the XSL into the XML document?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm embedding an HTML control in our CRM system, and using it to display a bit of XML. I want to format this using an XSL document.

Everything works fine when I test it locally with a test.xml and a test.xsl, but of course when I change the XSL link to

```
\\servername\share\test.xsl
```

then it doesn't work, I imagine because the location is not trusted.

Can I in-line the XSL into the XML document?  How else could I format the contents of a Browser control when I can't really use relative paths?

Thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention that the XML is being generated by a .Net app using XMLDocument etc

Comment: `\servername\share`? Have you tried putting the XSL on a web server, along with the XML? This should work.

Comment: Well, the XML is generated and stored in a DB field, and just diplayed in a browser control on a form - it doesn't actually exist anywhere "real".
For now, I've used the application's own per-user folder and copy the XSL file and the generated XML in there, that way it's all "local" to the browser.
Was hoping for an in-browser solution that didn't need temp files :(

Answer (score 0):

One technique I use quite often is to compile the XSLT into my .NET assembly as a manifest resource. If your XSLT file is in Visual Studio, in the file properties you can set "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource". The name of the resource then becomes the default namespace of the project followed by the name of the file (I think.... usually I compile the assembly and then check the name by poking around in the manifest with ILDASM).

Anyway - once you know the name, you can get the transform with a function like this (Note, this is in my utilities assembly, hence GetCallingAssembly.... in a different design you might use GetExecutingAssembly):

```
public static XslCompiledTransform GetTransformByResourceName(string resourceName)
{
  XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform(false);
  using (Stream manifestResourceStream = 
            Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
  using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(manifestResourceStream))
  {
    XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(false, false);
    transform.Load(reader, settings, new XmlUrlResolver());
  }
  return transform;
}
```

Of course in some ways, you lose some flexibility/configurability, but at least you know your code will be able to find the XSLT.

I don't know enough of your design to know whether moving the transform to the server would help. Even if you have to do the transform client side, if you're already serving the XML from a .NET application, then serving the XSLT too would probably work, but in this case without having to deploy it to file system separately.